# Spring MVC java mail IMAP, how to display list of emails received through a form in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, email, thymeleaf

I am making an email client application, for that I am using Spring MVC and the "javax.mail" mail API, in addition to thymeleaf for the view. I already configured the service to read messages through IMAP, so far so good, the problem I have is that when I try to show the list of emails through a form in the view I can only see one item in the list despite that in the debug you can see that all the emails in the specified folder (inbox) are listed.
So how can I display the email list of the "inbox" folder through a form in thymeleaf?

```
public class ReadDto {

    private String from;
    private String subject;
    private Date sentDate;

    public ReadDto() {
    }

    public ReadDto(String from, String subject, Date sentDate) {
        this.from = from;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.sentDate = sentDate;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public Date getSentDate() {
        return sentDate;
    }

    public void setSentDate(Date sentDate) {
        this.sentDate = sentDate;
    }
}
```

my service:

```
public interface EmailReadService {
    ReadDto downloadEmails();
}
```

Implementation:

```
    @Override
    public ReadDto downloadEmails(){

        ReadDto readDto = new ReadDto();

        if (getLoginSession()==null){
            logger.error("Session error!");
        }

        try {
            store = getLoginSession().getStore(emailAccountComponent.getProtocol());
            store.connect(connectService.javaMailSenderImpl.getHost(),
                        connectService.javaMailSenderImpl.getUsername(),
                        connectService.javaMailSenderImpl.getPassword());

            folder = store.getFolder(emailAccountComponent.getFolder());
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            Message[] messages = folder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
            for (Message message: messages){
                readDto.setFrom(Arrays.toString(message.getFrom()));
                readDto.setSubject(message.getSubject());
                readDto.setSentDate(message.getSentDate());
            }
            folder.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            System.out.println("No provider.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return readDto;
    }
```

My controller

```
    @GetMapping("/read")
    public String getEmails(Model model){
        ReadDto readDto = emailReadService.downloadEmails();
        model.addAttribute("emails", readDto);
        return READ_VIEW;
    }
```

in the view:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Sent date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="readDto: ${emails}">
                <td><span th:text="${emails.from}"> From </span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${emails.subject}"> Subject </span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${emails.sentDate}"> Sent date </span></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<tr th:each="readDto: ${emails}">
    <td><span th:text="${emails.from}"> From </span></td>
    <td><span th:text="${emails.subject}"> Subject </span></td>
    <td><span th:text="${emails.sentDate}"> Sent date </span></td>
</tr>
```

You need to use this:

```
<tr th:each="readDto : ${emails}">
    <td><span th:text="${readDto.from}"> From </span></td>
    <td><span th:text="${readDto.subject}"> Subject </span></td>
    <td><span th:text="${readDto.sentDate}"> Sent date </span></td>
</tr>
```

The `readDto` variable represents each object in the `${emails}` collection.

Then, after that, you need to ensure that the `readDTO` object populated from here...

```
ReadDto readDto = emailReadService.downloadEmails();
```

...is actually a collection not a single object. It needs to be something like this:

```
public interface EmailReadService {
    List<ReadDto> downloadEmails();
}
```

Right now, your code returns one email via the above interface:

```
for (Message message: messages){
    readDto.setFrom(Arrays.toString(message.getFrom()));
    readDto.setSubject(message.getSubject());
    readDto.setSentDate(message.getSentDate());
}
```

So, you need to store each of these `readDto` objects in a list, as you create them.

Comment: Thanks for the help andrewjames, you are absolutely right, with your help I already managed to get the entire email list, thanks again!